# DOSBox close immediately after opening TC and dos game

Tags: software-installation, dosbox

whenever i open TC and games like dave in DOSBox.DOSBox close immediately without any error.currently i'm using ubuntu 16.04 with gnome.
thank you!

Comment: "TC"? "dave"? "DOSBox"? what do these words mean?

Comment: TC = Turbo C, Dave = Dangerous Dave (DOS game) and DOSBox is a cross-platform emulator for running old-style DOS applications.